# API says : 'Endpoint/ does not exist' Though Im using the same URL provided by the API creator

Tags: javascript, rest

So Im working on a project for university assignment
Im trying to hook up a ChatBot API from RapidAPI.com.

Starting from the top - I copy pasted the code given by the developer, and no matter what it returns
/Endpoint/does not exist/

I have made some modifications, but if anyone can see why it may return that, I would highly appreciate it. Here is my code

```js
function onButtonClick(){
            
            //uses userInput, creates value. 
            const userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value
            const value = 0;
            //basic url for API string to get parsed in to the API call
            const apiString = "https://chatbot-chatari.p.rapidapi.com/?message=%2F";
            console.log(apiString + "API STRING NO MESSAGE")
            
            
            //basic url with message added on, known as value.
            const apiStringWithMessage = apiString + value;
            console.log(apiStringWithMessage + "API STRING WITH MESSAGE")

            //obselete
            //JSON.stringify(apiStringWithMessage);
    
    
            //setting up options, contains API GET / POST method etc. 
            //Sets up API key and Host URL
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'myapikey',
                'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'chatbot-chatari.p.rapidapi.com'
            }
        };


        //fetch uses URL with message hardcoded (right now), combined with options.
        //try catches to find errors, or show result.
        fetch('https://chatbot-chatari.p.rapidapi.com/?message=%2FHi!', options)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
```

Comment: Does this URL work? https://chatbot-chatari.p.rapidapi.com/message?message=%2FHi!

Comment: @AndrewShearer

That didnt :( It saw it as a request for a file on my pc.

Comment: Try to change your method from `method: 'POST',` to `method: 'GET'`, what's your response code?